# Acceso remoto a MySQL MAC

Tags: mysql, xampp, raspberry-pi

espero me puedan ayudar.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para raspberry. Para esta aplicación necesito conectarme a una base de datos que está montada en XAMPP para mac, pero no he encontrado la forma de acceder remotamente a la base de datos. Necesito hacer consultas a esa base de datos que está en mi mac. He buscado tutoriales pero no he tenido éxito. ¿Como puedo acceder a esa base de datos que está en mi mac desde raspberry? Mi única intención es poder tener los dos equipos (MAC y raspberry) dentro de una red local, el servicio no lo pondre en internet ni nada de eso.

NOTA: Desarrolle una aplicación web que debe mostrar datos que se traen desde la raspberry, por eso tengo todo montado en mi mac :).